# Change textview color with single button in android

Tags: android, button, colors, textview

This is my code:

```
   tv.setTextColor(getResourves().getColor(R.color.white));
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (the color is bgreen){
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }else if (the color is white){
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgreen));
            }
        }
    });
```

where,

```
<color name="bgreen">#ccff00</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

So the problem is that I'm not getting the code for-- if() and else if() statement.
There is solution for default colors but what to do in case of color strings. I want to switch between two colors with the same button.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: add a field to your class (Activit or Fragment) of type `boolean` named `isGreen`, and set it to `true` when you change color to green, and to false when you set white. When you need to know if your button is grean or not - check the `isGreen` value.

Comment: Check my post its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if(tv.getCurrentTextColor()== ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white))
              tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bgreen));
          else if(tv.getCurrentTextColor()== ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.bgreen))
              tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tv.setTextColor(getResourves().getColor(R.color.white));
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) tv.getBackground();

int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();

if (colorID == R.color.green){
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

else if(colorID == R.color.white){
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgreen));
}
}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     //Default color : White 
     boolean isWhite= true;
            tv.setTextColor(getResourves().getColor(R.color.white));

         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isWhite){

             isWhite= false;
             tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgreen));

         else{
             isWhite= true;
             tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();
        int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
        if (colorId == ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bgreen)) {
            tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        } else if (colorId == ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)) {
            tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bgreen));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.setTextColor(getResourves().getColor(R.color.white));
int whiteTextColour=tv.getCurrentTextColor();
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
if (tv.getCurrentTextColour()!=whiteTextColour){
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
else{
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgreen));
}
}
    });
```